# List view opens the same activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have successfully call activity on an item. but the problem is I already add a bracket but It still calls the two activity even on other item on the list view.

```
 mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        if(position==0);
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(Lessons1.this, ForthActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        if(position==1);
            Intent i = new Intent(Lessons1.this, ForthActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
});
}
}
```

Comment: brother you are calling both time same activity i.e. ForthActivity.class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never add a semicolon after an if statement. This

```
if(position==0);
{
    // some stuff
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if(position==0)
{
    // do nothing
}
{
    // some stuff
}
```

which means that you always do "some stuff" irrespective of the value of `position`.

Answer (score 1):

this

```
    if(position==1);
        Intent i = new Intent(Lessons1.this, ForthActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

should be

```
    if(position==1){
        Intent i = new Intent(Lessons1.this, ForthActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

New:

```
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(position==0){
            Intent i = new Intent(Lessons1.this, ForthActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        if(position==1){
            Intent i = new Intent(Lessons1.this, ForthActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
});
```

BTW you u notice you are calling the same activity

Comment: he closed the if() with ; and forgot a {

Comment: i will give you plus one but there is no need to give the answer question like this. it would be resolved by the comment only brother

Comment: @Ravind Maurya I believe the problem was that 2 activities were started